# Only one job is being executed in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

I made this .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
stages:
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind
  script:
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"

  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://my.awesome.vps
  only:
    - master
```

But when I run the pipeline only the publish job is executed.

[image: Gitlab screenshot]

I was reading the documentation for a while but it looks that my code is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, the pipeline seems to be executed on the `main` branch. However in your pipeline, the `deploy` step contains the following

```
  only:
    - master
```

This will limit the `deploy` job to be executed only if the branch is named `master`. That's why only the `publish` step got executed

Comment: That was the issue! thanks